# variable as functional binding

Tags: python, recursion, shadowing

Is there anyway in python to use shadowing so that this code does not loop forever?

Here, `ret` is a variable and not just a binding, leading to infinite recursion

```py
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, value, next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

def list2LinkedListFoldrImp(nums):
  ret = lambda x:x
  for num in nums:
    ret = lambda rs: ret(Node(num,rs)) # RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
  return ret(None)

print(list2LinkedListFoldrImp([5,4,1]))
```

Comment: convert the list [5,4,1] to the linked list Node(5,Node(4,Node(1,None)))

Comment: the data structures is recursive, so you do need some form of recursion. Think about `i = i + 1`, you would not expect that to recurse forever. this is the same, except with a functional value `ret`. this is a boiled down albeit contrived example

Comment: I do wish to use functions just like any other values, without relying on clever tricks if possible.

Comment: I fail to see how that is relevant

Comment: the question, highlighted in this simple code, is to recursively build a function, `ret`, whose job is to transform a list into a linked list...  this is just the most simple example one could think of.

Comment: This seems overly clever and non-pythonic on a few levels. Create a head node, get a reference to it and loop, populating `.next`s. Beyond that, basically never use a linked list like this anyway: there's `collections.deque` and `list` that is going to cover 99.99% of use cases involving linked lists, both of which are far faster and more idiomatic than rolling your own class.

Comment: continuations and function building is pretty much needed when you want to represent control in any language... the linked list is just a trivial example I came up with to look into it. there is a solution elsewhere which I will post

Answer (score 0):

The problem highlight the fact that only arguments in function calls can be captured in python, presumably because environments are created there only and otherwise mutated. Due to this mixed scoping, we can't just capture variables anywhere.

```py
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, value, next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

# simple and correct (sans recursion)
def list2LinkedListFoldrImp(nums):
  ret = lambda x:x
  for num in nums:
    ret = lambda rs,num=num,ret=ret: ret(Node(num,rs))
  return ret(None)
print('ok foldr', list2LinkedListFoldrImp([5,4,1]))
```